# In Flutter, how to extract frame by frame from an animated gif?

Tags: flutter, image, extract, frame, animated-gif

I'm trying to extract frames from an animated gif using Flutter. By researching the Flutter API, I thought the following code should work but it only gives me the first frame although it gives me the correct frames count.

```
static Future<List<ui.Image>> loadAnimatedGif(String assetPath) async {
    List<ui.Image> gifImage = [];
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
    var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    int frmCnt = codec.frameCount;
    print("frmcnt is $frmCnt"); //it gives correct frames count
    for (int i = 0; i < frmCnt; i++) {
      var frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
      gifImage.add(frame.Image);
     
    }
   
    return gifImage;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple app out of this and it works using the same code but added a converter in it.

What I notice at first because nothing

1. Using the `ui.Image` loads the frames but it delays for about 10secs before showing all of them using a breakpoint to debug it.
2. Converting `ui.Image` to `Uint8List` takes time as much as the frames but the format shows all frames as soon the extraction is done.

Here is the [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=467d52dddfc1e3806c79c9cf32a3126a) to quickly run and test it.

Here is the code if you will like to scan through it, I am loading the gif from Network.

```
class GifFramesDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  const GifFramesDisplay({super.key});

  @override
  State<GifFramesDisplay> createState() => _GifFramesDisplayState();
}

class _GifFramesDisplayState extends State<GifFramesDisplay> {
  List<Uint8List> _frames = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadGif();
  }

  Future<void> loadGif() async {
    // Load the gif image from the network url and store the bytes in a ByteData object
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aman-Malhotra/animate_icons/main/demo/animate_icons.gif');
    final ByteData data = await NetworkAssetBundle(url).load(url.path);

    // Using the _extractGifFrames function to extract the frames
    _extractGifFrames(data).then((List<Uint8List> frames) {
      // Set the state to update the UI
      setState(() {
        _frames = frames;
      });
    });
  }

  // Function to extract gif image frames
  Future<List<Uint8List>> _extractGifFrames(ByteData data) async {
    // Create a list to store the frames
    final List<Uint8List> frames = <Uint8List>[];

    // Create a codec to decode the gif
    final ui.Codec codec =
        await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());

    // Count the number of frames in the gif
    final int frameCount = codec.frameCount;
    print('Total frameCount: $frameCount');

    // Loop through the frames and add them to the list
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
      // Get the next frame
      final ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();

      // Add the frame to the list
      final frame = await loadImage(fi.image);

      // Add the frame to the list if it is not null
      if (frame != null) {
        frames.add(frame);
      }
    }

    return frames;
  }

  Future<Uint8List?> loadImage(ui.Image image) async {
    final ByteData? byteData =
        await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData?.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _frames.isEmpty
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _frames.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Image.memory(_frames[index]);
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Click](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46024202/209590375-dfa4c568-cc42-4b18-aedc-ddfd5aff10a6.mp4) to watch a preview of the loaded gif frames of the code above